# Which tool can I use to visualize FIX message exchange?

Tags: fix-protocol

Is there some tool (or a plug-in) I can use to visualize FIX messages, preferably with support of multiple messages being exchanged (FIX scenarios).

I know there are bunch of online-tools, but I'm looking for something to use off-line.

Online FIX parsers:

1. https://fixparser.targetcompid.com/
2. http://fix.aprics.net/
3. https://drewnoakes.com/fix-decoder/

Comment: for drewnoakes's fixdecoder, even if all decoding happens in your browser, you can easily `git clone https://github.com/drewnoakes/fix-decoder.git` and run it locally over your favorite httpd... maybe you want to remove the google-analytics...

Comment: in addition to the 3 listed above these is also https://fixparser.chronicle.software

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with packet captures/raw data, [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) has a built-in FIX decoder which works very very well. Its built-in tools work nicely for most FIX flows.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use WireShark

Comment: Tried WireShark at home, works pretty well, but I'm more interested in something to feed my logs with.